# ValueError: seek of closed file | pdfplumber

Tags: python, pdf

I am writing a program that it will extract text from a PDF file using library `pdfplumber` and I am getting the following error in the last 3 iterations before the end of the for loop.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

```py
def changePDF():
    numPages = int(input("how many pages does your pdf have? --> "))
    for i in range(numPages):
        with pdfplumber.open(r'test.pdf') as pdf:
            page = pdf.pages[i]
            print(f"working on page {i}")
    print(page.extract_text())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with pdfplumber but I can make an educated guess that `page` does not hold all of the data from the file but instead references a location within an open file handle.  Once you leave your `with` block, that file handle is closed and you can no longer access the data.

What you can do is move the `with` line outside of your `for` loop and do all of your interaction with the PDF inside that block.  That is,

```
with pdfplumber.open(r'test.pdf') as pdf:
    for i in range(numPages):
        page = pdf.pages[i]
        print(f"working on page {i}")
        print(page.extract_text())
```